# Volley - JsonObjectRequest - parseNetworkResponse() is not being called

Tags: android, android-volley

I would like to save response code from volley calls to db, but it seems like parseNetworkResponse() is not being called. Any idea why does it behave like this?

All of my calls are GET, some has code 500 and some has code 200 with json response, so I think it should be called.

```
private fun createCall(url: String, type: Int, data: JSONObject, callback: Int, request: DbRequestEntity) {
    val jsonRequest = object : JsonObjectRequest(type, url, data,
            Response.Listener { response ->
                Log.d(tag, "Response $response")
                try {
                    callback(response, data, callback, request)
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    request.responseCode = 999
                    request.responseMessage = e.message
                    db.requestMoodel().update(request)
                    Log.d(tag, "API callback error $e ${e.localizedMessage} ${e.stackTrace}")
                }
            },
            Response.ErrorListener { error ->
                Log.d(tag, "API error $error")
                errorCallback(error, callback)
            }
    ) {
        val tag = "JsonObjectRequest"

        override fun getHeaders(): Map<String, String> {
            val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
            headers[ConstantsStorage.API_HEADER_CLIENT_ID] = ConstantsStorage.API_HEADER_CLIENT_ID_VALUE
            headers[ConstantsStorage.API_HEADER_CLIENT_CONTENT_TYPE] = ConstantsStorage.API_HEADER_CLIENT_CONTENT_TYPE_VALUE
            return headers
        }

        override fun parseNetworkResponse(response: NetworkResponse): Response<JSONObject> {
            Log.d(tag, "Response code = ${response.statusCode}")     //not getting this message to Logcat
            return super.parseNetworkResponse(response)
        }
    }
    queue.add(jsonRequest)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your parseNetworkResponse function with below code

```
override fun parseNetworkResponse(response: NetworkResponse): Response<JSONObject> {
            try {
        if (response.data.length == 0) {
            byte[] responseData = "{}".getBytes("UTF8");
            response = new NetworkResponse(response.statusCode, responseData, response.headers, response.notModified);
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
            return super.parseNetworkResponse(response)
        }
```

Comment: After deleting you will get the response in on response methos there you can parse you response

Comment: Well, but I am getting response and everything is working for me, all I need to do is get statusCode so I added parseNetworkResponse but it seems like its not being called and I dont know why.